# Why does accuracy remain the same

Tags: machine-learning, keras, tensorflow

I'm new to machine learning and I try to create a simple model myself. The idea is to train a model that predicts if a value is more or less than some threshold.

I generate some random values before and after threshold and create the model

```py
import os
import random

import numpy as np
from keras import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from random import shuffle

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
threshold = 50000
samples = 5000

train_data = []
for i in range(0, samples):
    train_data.append([random.randrange(0, threshold), 0])
    train_data.append([random.randrange(threshold, 2 * threshold), 1])

data_set = np.array(train_data)
shuffle(data_set)

input_value = data_set[:, 0:1]
expected_result = data_set[:, 1]


model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(3, input_dim=1, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))

# compile the keras model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# fit the keras model on the dataset
model.fit(input_value, expected_result, epochs=10, batch_size=5)

_, accuracy = model.evaluate(input_value, expected_result)
print('Accuracy: %.2f' % (accuracy*100))
```

The problem is that accuracy is always about 0.5 and if I check the training process I see something like this.

```
Epoch 1/10

    5/10000 [..............................] - ETA: 8:07 - loss: 6.4472 - acc: 0.6000
  230/10000 [..............................] - ETA: 12s - loss: 7.4283 - acc: 0.5391 
  455/10000 [>.............................] - ETA: 7s - loss: 7.8642 - acc: 0.5121 
  675/10000 [=>............................] - ETA: 5s - loss: 7.9277 - acc: 0.5081
  890/10000 [=>............................] - ETA: 4s - loss: 7.7693 - acc: 0.5180
 1095/10000 [==>...........................] - ETA: 4s - loss: 7.9045 - acc: 0.5096
 1305/10000 [==>...........................] - ETA: 3s - loss: 7.8306 - acc: 0.5142
 1515/10000 [===>..........................] - ETA: 3s - loss: 7.7558 - acc: 0.5188
 1730/10000 [====>.........................] - ETA: 3s - loss: 7.7516 - acc: 0.5191
 1920/10000 [====>.........................] - ETA: 2s - loss: 7.7149 - acc: 0.5214
 2120/10000 [=====>........................] - ETA: 2s - loss: 7.7245 - acc: 0.5208
 2340/10000 [======>.......................] - ETA: 2s - loss: 7.7422 - acc: 0.5197
 2565/10000 [======>.......................] - ETA: 2s - loss: 7.7668 - acc: 0.5181
 2785/10000 [=======>......................] - ETA: 2s - loss: 7.8015 - acc: 0.5160
 3000/10000 [========>.....................] - ETA: 2s - loss: 7.9032 - acc: 0.5097
 3210/10000 [========>.....................] - ETA: 2s - loss: 7.9134 - acc: 0.5090
 3435/10000 [=========>....................] - ETA: 2s - loss: 7.9629 - acc: 0.5060
 3660/10000 [=========>....................] - ETA: 1s - loss: 7.9578 - acc: 0.5063
 3875/10000 [==========>...................] - ETA: 1s - loss: 7.9696 - acc: 0.5055
 4085/10000 [===========>..................] - ETA: 1s - loss: 7.9861 - acc: 0.5045
 4305/10000 [===========>..................] - ETA: 1s - loss: 7.9823 - acc: 0.5048
 4530/10000 [============>.................] - ETA: 1s - loss: 7.9737 - acc: 0.5053
 4735/10000 [=============>................] - ETA: 1s - loss: 8.0063 - acc: 0.5033
 4945/10000 [=============>................] - ETA: 1s - loss: 7.9955 - acc: 0.5039
 5160/10000 [==============>...............] - ETA: 1s - loss: 7.9935 - acc: 0.5041
 5380/10000 [===============>..............] - ETA: 1s - loss: 7.9991 - acc: 0.5037
 5605/10000 [===============>..............] - ETA: 1s - loss: 8.0432 - acc: 0.5010
 5805/10000 [================>.............] - ETA: 1s - loss: 8.0466 - acc: 0.5008
 6020/10000 [=================>............] - ETA: 1s - loss: 8.0189 - acc: 0.5025
 6240/10000 [=================>............] - ETA: 1s - loss: 8.0151 - acc: 0.5027
 6470/10000 [==================>...........] - ETA: 0s - loss: 7.9843 - acc: 0.5046
 6695/10000 [===================>..........] - ETA: 0s - loss: 7.9760 - acc: 0.5052
 6915/10000 [===================>..........] - ETA: 0s - loss: 7.9926 - acc: 0.5041
 7140/10000 [====================>.........] - ETA: 0s - loss: 8.0004 - acc: 0.5036
 7380/10000 [=====================>........] - ETA: 0s - loss: 7.9848 - acc: 0.5046
 7595/10000 [=====================>........] - ETA: 0s - loss: 7.9752 - acc: 0.5052
 7805/10000 [======================>.......] - ETA: 0s - loss: 7.9568 - acc: 0.5063
 8035/10000 [=======================>......] - ETA: 0s - loss: 7.9557 - acc: 0.5064
 8275/10000 [=======================>......] - ETA: 0s - loss: 7.9802 - acc: 0.5049
 8515/10000 [========================>.....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 7.9748 - acc: 0.5052
 8730/10000 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 7.9944 - acc: 0.5040
 8955/10000 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 7.9934 - acc: 0.5041
 9190/10000 [==========================>...] - ETA: 0s - loss: 7.9854 - acc: 0.5046
 9430/10000 [===========================>..] - ETA: 0s - loss: 7.9975 - acc: 0.5038
 9650/10000 [===========================>..] - ETA: 0s - loss: 8.0190 - acc: 0.5025
 9865/10000 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 8.0337 - acc: 0.5016
10000/10000 [==============================] - 3s 255us/step - loss: 8.0397 - acc: 0.5012
```

I tried to change the layers count and the number of nodes in the layer but the result is basically the same. What am I missing to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two separate problems going on.

## Use `sigmoid`

First, when performing a binary classification problem, you should set the activation of your final layer to `sigmoid` (or `softmax`, which is equivalent in the binary classification case).

## Scale your data

Second, when using neural networks, it's important to make sure your data is of a "reasonable" scale. A "reasonable" scale is usually something in the range of a 0-mean, unit-variance normal distribution.

## Effect of fixing these issues

Let's look at the effect of fixing these issues after 5 epochs.

If I change your last layer to `sigmoid`:

```
model.add(Dense(3, input_dim=1, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

I get ~94% accuracy:

```
Epoch 1/5
10000/10000 [==============================] - 1s 127us/sample - loss: 107.2031 - acc: 0.5594
Epoch 2/5
10000/10000 [==============================] - 1s 118us/sample - loss: 0.8730 - acc: 0.6688
Epoch 3/5
10000/10000 [==============================] - 1s 118us/sample - loss: 0.6432 - acc: 0.7455
Epoch 4/5
10000/10000 [==============================] - 1s 119us/sample - loss: 0.5688 - acc: 0.7899
Epoch 5/5
10000/10000 [==============================] - 1s 119us/sample - loss: 0.3340 - acc: 0.8631
10000/10000 [==============================] - 0s 10us/sample - loss: 0.2087 - acc: 0.9440
Accuracy: 94.40
```

If I change keep the last activation as `sigmoid`, but *also* scale your input values to be between 0 and 1:

```
    train_data.append([random.randrange(0, threshold) / 100000, 0])
    train_data.append([random.randrange(threshold, 2 * threshold) / 100000, 1])
```

Then I get 99.8% accuracy.

```
Epoch 1/5
10000/10000 [==============================] - 1s 128us/sample - loss: 0.5206 - acc: 0.7013
Epoch 2/5
10000/10000 [==============================] - 1s 114us/sample - loss: 0.2051 - acc: 0.9732
Epoch 3/5
10000/10000 [==============================] - 1s 115us/sample - loss: 0.1083 - acc: 0.9943
Epoch 4/5
10000/10000 [==============================] - 1s 116us/sample - loss: 0.0697 - acc: 0.9953
Epoch 5/5
10000/10000 [==============================] - 1s 116us/sample - loss: 0.0512 - acc: 0.9967
10000/10000 [==============================] - 0s 10us/sample - loss: 0.0450 - acc: 0.9980
Accuracy: 99.80
```

Comment: I changed all you mentioned but I still had accuracy of ~50%, I also needed to change `model.fit` to `model.fit(input_value, expected_result, epochs=5, batch_size=1)`  and I got accuracy 99.18

Comment: Thanks a lot,it becomes more clear :)

Answer (score -1):

The problem i am seeing here is that you are using the same `train_data` for both `training` and `evaluation` of model.I would recommend you to use a `shuffled subset` of `train_data` as `test_data` or `validation_data` and try to `evaluate` your model on it.

Comment: I agree you should use a different data set for training and testing, but how does that address the problem of the accuracy staying the same during training?